# React-Router-Redux / Sagas / Push Undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga, react-router-redux

I'm stuck on an error happening in a Saga when attempting to use react-router-redux 5.0.0-alpha.9.

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
import ReactOnRails from 'react-on-rails';
import { call, put, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { LOGIN, loginSuccess, loginFailure } from '../users/actions';
import loginService from './services';

function* loginSaga(action) {
  const { loginValues } = action;

  try {
    const loginData = yield call(loginService, loginValues);
    const store = ReactOnRails.getStore('appStore', false);
    yield put(loginSuccess(loginData));
    yield call(store.dispatch(push('/')));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(loginFailure(error.response.data.error));
  }
}

function* loginWatcherSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(LOGIN, loginSaga);
}

export default loginWatcherSaga;
```

The issue happens on login success.  It will successfully call the 'loginSuccess' action and then go to the `yield call(store.dispatch(push('/')));` line, but it bombs and jumps to the catch.  Here's the error message:

```
utils.js:225 uncaught at check call: argument fn is undefined
log @ utils.js:225
check @ utils.js:29
getFnCallDesc @ io.js:88
call @ io.js:113
loginSaga @ sagas.js:14
next @ proc.js:311
currCb @ proc.js:388
(anonymous) @ proc.js:499
exec @ scheduler.js:19
flush @ scheduler.js:60
asap @ scheduler.js:33
runPutEffect @ proc.js:486
runEffect @ proc.js:435
next @ proc.js:315
currCb @ proc.js:388
Promise.then (async)
resolvePromise @ proc.js:450
runCallEffect @ proc.js:517
runEffect @ proc.js:435
next @ proc.js:315
proc @ proc.js:270
runForkEffect @ proc.js:554
runEffect @ proc.js:435
next @ proc.js:315
currCb @ proc.js:388
takeCb @ proc.js:466
put @ channel.js:73
(anonymous) @ channel.js:161
(anonymous) @ channel.js:186
exec @ scheduler.js:19
flush @ scheduler.js:60
asap @ scheduler.js:33
(anonymous) @ channel.js:185
emit @ channel.js:26
(anonymous) @ middleware.js:67
login @ LoginForm.jsx:131
handleSubmit @ LoginForm.jsx:31
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:542
```

Essentially it is bombing on this line:

```
yield call(store.dispatch(push('/')));
```

When I debug into it, push is undefined.  I have no reason why.  I have this exact code working in a different saga:

```
function* setPasswordSaga(action) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(setPasswordService, action.passwordValues);
    const store = ReactOnRails.getStore('appStore', false);
    yield put(setPasswordSuccess(response));
    yield call(store.dispatch(push('/')));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(setPasswordFailure(error.response.data.user));
  }
}
```

It changes the routing just fine.  I haven't been able to figure out why one works and the other doesn't.  Any ideas?

Is there a better way to do this?  I was trying to do the routing in the action, but the state wasn't updating in the component before it was being rendered so I have to somehow execute the service, update the state, then update the route.  Confused on the best way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with `yield put(push(YOUR_ROUTE))`